Why does Germanic poetry have special rules regarding alliteration with words starting with the letter s?
In Germanic poetry such as the edda and Beowulf, consonant cluster words starting with the letter s have special rules about alliteration.
From Wikipedia, using Minkova 2003 as a source:

The consonant clusters st-, sp- and sc- are treated as separate sounds (so st- only alliterates with st-, not with s- or sp-)

My question is: Why? I understand that identical versus related but different consonant clusters are not the same poetic device, but whence comes this particular strictness in the case of words beginning with the letter s? Why is it absent from other words?
Why is "the price of peace" more poetically elegant than "the stranger sees"?
Even if it's just an intuitive feeling that makes it sound better, I'm still interested in potential psychological reasons and explanations for why.
Speculative and artistically justified answers are accepted, even without historical sources.

The only initial consonant clusters containing three consonants in English start with /sp/, /sk/, or /st/  — e.g., split, squat, street. Maybe this has something to do with it.

This is a well-known puzzle in the study of Germanic poetry, but one that has not yet been solved.

One of the peculiarities of Germanic alliterative verse, frequently noticed, but never really explained in terms of the phonetic properties of the segments involved, is the well-known phenomenon of cluster alliteration.
Donka Minkova (2003). Alliteration and Sound Change in Early English, page 192. Cambridge University Press.

Problem
The explanation is likely to be psycholinguistic: that is, Old English speakers perceived the st‑ initial consonant cluster as a single cohesive sound, and not (as modern English speakers perceive it) as the combination of two separate sounds represented by “s” and “t”, and similarly for sc‑ and sp‑.
To appeciate how this can happen, consider the sound represented by “ch” in words like “cheese” and “chips” in modern English. We perceive this as a single sound, and not as the combination of two separate sounds represented by “t” and “sh”. This means that, in modern English, “cheese” does not alliterate with “turnip”: even though both words start with the same sound (a voiceless alveolar stop), they are perceived differently by native speakers.
However, no-one has as yet put forward a really convincing explanation for how this worked for sc‑ etc. Psycholinguistic phenomena leave few traces in the historical record—if not for alliterative verse we might have no idea it even existed—and there are no speakers we can ask.
There are two main sub-problems: (A) what made sc‑, sp‑ and st‑ different from sl‑, sm‑, sn‑ and sw‑, and (B) what changed so that this distinction went away? In English the distinction was already on the way out by the end of the 10th century. Ælfric, for example, writing in the 990s, freely alliterated sc‑, sp‑, and st‑ with other words starting s‑:

1.83 Nu ƿylle ƿe eoƿ sū þing be eoƿre saƿle sæccgan · sceortlice gif ƿé magon.
now will we, if we can, briefly tell you something about your own souls
2.188 ác ic hrymde sona mid sarlicre stæmne
But I cried aloud quickly with sorrowful voice
5.193 sæde hú hí spræcon · ⁊ hine sona gelædde
told how they had conversed, and brought him at once
Ælfric of Eynsham (997). Lives of the Saints. Translated by Walter Skeat (1881). Wikisource.

(In trying to date this change, we have to bear in mind that written language often lags behind spoken language, and that a rule may continue to be followed because it is traditional. For example, poets in English continued to use “thou” long after it had disappeared from ordinary language.)
Proposals
Minkova (2003) surveyed proposed solutions to the problem, before presenting her own. The proposals can be very briefly summarized:

sc‑ changed to be pronounced like “sh”, for example, “scyld” → “shield”.
sc‑, sp‑ and st‑ are the only initial clusters that violate the sonority sequencing principle. [See below.]
/s/-adjunction. [Seiichi Suzuki (1996). The Metrical Organization of Beowulf: Prototype and Isomorphism. Berlin: Mouton de Gruyter.]
/s/-syllabification. [Rebecca Treiman, Jennifer Gross, and Annemarie Cwikiel-Glavin (1992). ‘The syllabification of /s/ clusters in English’. Journal of Phonetics 20, pages 383–402.]
Contour structures. [Piotr Gąsiorowski (1997). The Phonology of Old English Stress and Metrical Structure. Frankfurt am Main: Peter Lang.]
Glottal spreading. [Gregory Iverson and Joseph Salmons (1999). ‘Glottal spreading bias in Germanic.’ Linguistische Berichte 178, pages 135–151.]
sc‑, sp‑ and st‑ are the only initial clusters that lack a perceptual break. [Minkova (2003).]

I don’t know enough about phonology to follow some of these proposals, let alone evaluate their plausibility. You’ll have to look up the references for yourself. However, Minkova is skeptical about (1)–(6) on the grounds that they fail to solve (A) or (B) or both. For example, (1) fails (A)—it only explains sc‑ and not sp‑ and st‑ and also (B)—the sound change happened too late, after the alliteration rule was already in use. In the case of Minkova’s proposal (7), there is something circular in the idea of a “perceptual break”, and I am not convinced that it solves (B), since there is no explanation of what changed in the tenth century. But as I say, I am not an expert and you should read the theory for yourself.
However, maybe some of these proposals have a piece of the puzzle, if not the whole picture, so I will discuss one of them in more detail.
Sonority sequencing
“Sonority” is the amplitude or loudness of speech sounds. Minkova explains the sonority sequencing principle (SSP) as follows:

One of the basic tenets of syllabic phonology is that there is an optimal left-to-right arrangement of segments preceding the syllable peak. Sievers (1901: §527) defined the principle succinctly: “the closer to the syllabic segment [a consonant is], the greater its sonority must be.”† This means that syllable onsets are “best” when they display gradient sonority (Abstufung der Schallfü̈lle)–from low to high. Conceptually, the rising sonority of onset clusters is a universal property of syllable structure, though the details of the sonority hierarchy can be language-specific. For English, the phonetic specification of some sounds in terms of percentage values of the traditional feature [sonorant], defined numerically in relation to the amount of acoustic energy present during the production of the sound, are given [as follows]:



p t k
f θ h
s ʃ
w j
m n ɹ
l i
ι
æ ɔ oῶ




0
5
15
70
75
80
85
95



† Sievers, Eduard (1901). Grundzüge der Phonetik zur Einführung in das Studium der Lautlehre der indogermanischen Sprachen, fünfte verbesserte Auflage. Leipzig: Druck und Verlag von Breitkopf & Härtel.
Minkova, page 203.

What this means is that within the onset of a syllable, sounds are usually ordered from least to most sonorant. This explains, for example, why English has words starting “thr‑” like “thread” and “three” but lacks words starting “rth‑”: the “th” sound (θ in the table) is less sonorant than “r” (ɹ in the table) and so comes first according to the SSP.
It is therefore noteworthy that the three consonant clusters that alliterate specially also break the SSP: the sound “s” comes first, but it is more sonorant than “p”, “t” and “k”, and so ought to come second according to the SSP. This might explain (A), but unfortunately not (B) since these clusters continue to violate the SSP but we no longer consider them too cohesive to alliterate with other words starting “s”.

Worth noting also that in many languages consonant combinations are considered single letters, e.g., «ts» which is rendered c in Slavic languages using the Roman alphabet and ц in those using the Cyrillic alphabet, or more dramatically, the «shch» combination which is rendered either šč or щ. German tends to use multiple letters for single sounds (e.g., cz for «ch» and ch for «kh») so I can see how they would consider «sp» «sk» etc. as single sounds for the sake of alliteration (and I kind of feel like scones skipping scooters has more alliterative vibe than stones skipping spies.)
